# how to acces data of <memory at 0x000...> coming from psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

Basicaly I'm using psycopg2 and I want to save a couple of images in the ByteA[] Array

```py
entries = psycopg2.connect("postgres://private")


with entries:
    with entries.cursor() as cu:
        cu.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
        print(cu.fetchall())
        # This returns: [([<memory at 0x00000...>, <memory at 0x00000...>])]


def submit():
    binary_values = (b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82',
                     b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82')
    with entries:
        with entries.cursor() as cu:
            cu.execute("INSERT INTO test (photos) VALUES (ARRAY[%s, %s]);", binary_values)
```

But when I try to access it, it gives me  <memory at 0x00000...> instead of the bytes for the images, how can I fix that??

I need them returned like they look like in the list so I can display them in my website

Answer (score 1):

Psycopg2 returns BYTEA values as [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) objects. They can often be used directly where you would otherwise use `bytes` objects, or converted to `bytes` objects by passing them to the `bytes(...)` constructor.